# Pandas merge rows with same start and end time

Tags: python, database, pandas, time-series, data-science

I have a file with several data from wifi access. The database is divided in multiple columns : user_id, start (when the device connect to the router), end (when the device disconnect from the router).

Exemple :

```
user_id   start     end 
1   15/05/16 13:51  15/05/16 14:06 
1   15/05/16 14:06  15/05/16 14:32 
1   15/05/16 14:32  15/05/16 14:34 
2   15/05/16 11:14  15/05/16 11:25 
2   15/05/16 11:25  15/05/16 12:09 
2   15/05/16 12:14  15/05/16 12:42 
2   15/05/16 17:33  15/05/16 17:41 
2   15/05/16 17:41  15/05/16 18:27
```

The problem is, sometime the devices disconnect and reconnect. I would like to group the data in event like that:

```
user_id start   end
1   15/05/16 13:51  15/05/16 14:34
2   15/05/16 11:14  15/05/16 12:42
2   15/05/16 17:33  15/05/16 18:27
```

Is there an efficient way to do it with pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, we need to have columns: 'start' and 'end' in the right format:

```
df[['start']] =pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df[['end']] =pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
```

Then you need generate a new column to identify the condition of a different connection:

```
df['id_connection'] = False
```

The next step is identifying the first observation of a new user (it will always be a new connection):

```
indexes = df.drop_duplicates(subset='user_id', keep='first').index
df.loc[indexes,'id_connection'] = True
```

Now, we need to identify the another condition when a new connection is produced. You need take a criteria in order to determinate if it is a new connection or not:

```
diff_ = (df['start'].values[1:] - df['end'].values[:-1]).astype('float')
time_criteria_mins = 5
new_connection = np.insert(( diff_ / (60*10**9)) > time_criteria_mins, 0, 1)
```

Then, you need combine the two conditions, (1) new user (2) same user with a time between connection bigger than 5 minutes:

```
df['id_connection'] = (new_connection | df['id_connection']).cumsum()
```

Finally, we make a group by the attribute 'id_connection':

```
gb = df.groupby('id_connection').agg({'user_id': 'first', 'start': 'first','end':'last'})
```

Note: Be cautious in order to assure that the dataframe is sorted by (user and start datetime)

Answer (score 0):

We can have something like this

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1,'15/05/16 13:51','15/05/16 14:06'],
        [1,'15/05/16 14:06','15/05/16 14:32'], 
        [1,'15/05/16 14:32','15/05/16 14:34'], 
        [2,'15/05/16 11:14','15/05/16 11:25'],
        [2,'15/05/16 11:25','15/05/16 12:09'],
        [2,'15/05/16 12:14','15/05/16 12:42'],
        [2,'15/05/16 17:33','15/05/16 17:41'], 
        [2,'15/05/16 17:41','15/05/16 18:27']
    ]
    ,columns=['userid','start','end']
)

from datetime import datetime
data['start']=data['start'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%y %H:%M'))
data['end']=data['end'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%y %H:%M'))

diffData=[]
for i in range(1, len(data)):
    diffData.append((data.loc[i,'start'] - data.loc[i-1,'end']).seconds / 60)

data['diff']=[0] + diffData

def getStartEnd(tempData,THRESHOLD):
    tempData=tempData.reset_index()
    finalData=[]
    startTime=tempData.loc[0,'start']
    for i in range(1,len(tempData)):
        if(tempData.loc[i,'diff'] > THRESHOLD):
            finalData.append([tempData.loc[i,'userid'],startTime,tempData.loc[i-1,'end']])
            startTime=tempData.loc[i,'start']
    finalData.append([tempData.loc[i,'userid'],startTime,tempData.loc[i,'end']])
    return(pd.DataFrame(finalData,columns=['userid','start','end']))

finalData=pd.DataFrame(columns=['userid','start','end'])
for user in data['userid'].unique():
    finalData=pd.concat([finalData,getStartEnd(data[data['userid']==user],60)])

print(finalData)

  userid               start                 end
0      1 2016-05-15 13:51:00 2016-05-15 14:34:00
0      2 2016-05-15 11:14:00 2016-05-15 12:42:00
1      2 2016-05-15 17:33:00 2016-05-15 18:27:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas Groupby function on user id , once if you separated the each user id data, calculate the difference between start and end. Then apply cummulative sum to seperate groups and then you can extract start of first row and end of last row of each group :-)

```
def func(threshold,df1):
    # Calculating the difference of start and end time of each row
    df1['diff1'] = ((df1.start - df1.end.shift()).dt.seconds).fillna(0)
    # if difference is less than threshold equating with 0
    df1.loc[df1['diff1'] < threshold, 'diff1'] = 0
    # assigning cummulative sum of column
    df1['diff1'] = df1.diff1.cumsum()
    # Grouping the cummulatice sum of time differences and keeping only required row
    df1 = df1.groupby(['diff1']).apply(lambda x: x.set_value(0,'end',x['end'].tail(1).values[0]).loc[x.head(1).index.values[0]])
    return df1

data.start = pd.to_datetime(data.start)
data.end = pd.to_datetime(data.end) 
# Threshold setting to consider the difference "threshold is in seconds"
threshold = 500
# Calling the function for each ID
data.groupby('userid').apply(lambda x: func(threshold,x))
```

Out:

```
     userid        start                end        diff1
userid  diff1               
1        0.0    1.0 2016-05-15 13:51:00 2016-05-15 14:34:00 0.0
2        0.0    2.0 2016-05-15 11:14:00 2016-05-15 11:25:00 0.0
2     17460.0   2.0 2016-05-15 11:14:00 2016-05-15 11:25:00 0.0
```